# Presenting UIModalPresentationFormSheet, but appears as UIModalPresnetationPageSheet

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I've been googling what this problem is for over two hours to no avail.

What I am attempting to do is present "walkthrough" onto the screen as a formsheet. The modalPresentationStyle value is set correct throughout the hierarchy, yet "walkthrough" appears as a page sheet.

SYNavigationController just forwards -shouldAutoRotate and -supportedInterfaceOrientation to the topViewController.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this would happen? I've included the code below.

```
NSString *storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard_iPhone";
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard_iPad";

UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];

SYNavigationController *walkThrough = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"walkthroughNav"];
walkThrough.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

WalkThroughViewController *wtvc = (WalkThroughViewController *)walkThrough.topViewController;
wtvc.showSignIn = YES;

[self presentViewController:walkThrough animated:NO completion:nil];
```